# Event subscribe using function pointer : term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

This is Camera class which responds to mouse movements.

```
class Camera {
public:
    void processMouseMovement(double xPos, double yPos) {
        //rotating camera
    }
};
```

mouseEvent will be called when mouse is moved.
mouseCallbacks is a list of all functions that subscribe to mouseEvent.

```
#include<vector>
#include"Camera.h"

typedef void(__thiscall Camera::* mouseFunc)(double xPos, double yPos);

class InputSystem {
public:
    static std::vector<mouseFunc> mouseCallbacks;
    static void mouseEvent(double xPos, double yPos) {
        //some processing
        for (auto func : mouseCallbacks) {
            func(xPos, yPos); //error here
        }
    }
};
//subscribe camera processMouseMovement to mouseEvent
std::vector<mouseFunc> InputSystem::mouseCallbacks{ &Camera::processMouseMovement };
```

Main funtion

```
#include<iostream>
#include"InputSystem.h"

Camera camera; //global camera object
int main() {
    //simulating mouse event
    InputSystem::mouseEvent(1.0f, 2.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me a compilation error.

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

How can I call my function from function pointer `func`?
Is there any better way to store and call callbacks using function pointers?

Thanks

Comment: `mouseFunc` is a type-alias for a pointer to a non-static member function of `Camera`. To be able to call it you *must* have a `Camera` object. Objects can't be inferred, and aren't part of the pointer-type. You might want to consider [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: But you are not using function pointers, you are using pointers to class methods. These are not the same thing (which seems to be the source of your confusion). Apart from the options that Some programmer dude has mentioned the other would be to use actual function pointers `typedef void(__thiscall *mouseFunc)(double xPos, double yPos);`